# Why am i losing time when converting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good morning everyone!

I am trying (and failing) and converting times for some reason. What I am trying to do is reach out and grab all records in a table, then every once in a while reach out to the table and grab any new records that have been added to the table after a certain timestamp.

Just for testing purposes I have a table and am doing this manually for now.

my first step in the process is reaching out and grabbing a time that is in UTC format.

```
SELECT MAX(LastModified) FROM MWOPOL
```

***RESULT***: 2020-11-24T10:43:39.694Z

my next step would be converting this time to local time

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, '2020-11-24T10:43:39.694Z'), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS [LocalTime]
```

***RESULT***: 2020-11-24 05:43:39.694

I went with Varchar(23) instead of DATETIME because if I do I lose .001 of the time.
when I try to convert the time to local time

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),(DATEADD(HOUR,DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()),(('2020-11-24 05:43:39.694')))),127) AS [ConvertedBackToUTC]
```

***RESULT***: 2020-11-24T10:43:39.693

So when I convert the time back I still end up losing time. which can/will cause issues if there were records added at .694 i end up in a vicious cycle which will cause me to keep adding to the table even if there were new records added.

Comment: `datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second. It can't store `2020-11-24T05:43:39.694` so it stores it to the nearest value is value, `2020-11-24T10:43:39.6933333333~` = `2020-11-24T10:43:39.693`

Comment: Any good work around for this?

Comment: Don't use `datetime`, use `datetime2` which can be accurate up to 100 nanoseconds. `CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2020-11-24 05:43:39.694')` would fix the problem.

Comment: Also, note that in your first query you aren't using a `datetime`, you're using a `datetimeoffset(7)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DATETIME2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of DATETIME.
This should work for you:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, '2020-11-24T10:43:39.694Z'), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS [LocalTime]
```